# How do i set up borderbrush in radiobutton in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, radio-button

I have this code

```
<RadioButton  Content="Femenino" Height="72" Margin="224,118,0,0" Name="rbtn_fem" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible"
                              BorderBrush="#FFA3CD5A"  Background="White" 
                              BorderThickness="8" 
                              GroupName="selsex" Foreground="#FFA3CD5A"
                              FontWeight="ExtraBold" 
                              FontFamily="Fonts/Me Likey.ttf#Me Likey ~"/>
```

I have been trying to made a radio button with a green border and white center, but it seems that something is going wrong with the button borderbrush property, since no matter what color i change it, it doesnt appear.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in Windows Phone 7 the default control template for a RadioButton does not utilize the BorderBrush or BorderThickness properties.  You'll have to create your own ControlTemplate to use that does implement it through TemplateBinding.

For example, the following ControlTemplate simply has a Border added inside which binds to the appropriate properties.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledCheckBackground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedDarkCheckBackground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedLightCheckBackground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="EnabledCheckBackground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledDarkCheckBackground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledLightCheckBackground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckDisabledBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <!-- Here are the TemplateBindings for the BorderBrush and BorderThickness -->
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse x:Name="EnabledCheckBackground" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="{StaticResource PhoneDarkThemeOpacity}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="PressedDarkCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}" Height="32" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="DisabledDarkCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxDisabledBrush}" Height="32" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                </Canvas>
                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="{StaticResource PhoneLightThemeOpacity}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="PressedLightCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}" Height="32" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="DisabledLightCheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxDisabledBrush}" Height="32" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="32"/>
                </Canvas>
                <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,0,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1):

What problems are you seeing when you set these properties?

When I enter your code above into one of my apps' forms, I see the following, which appears to be what you're asking for (green outline with white inner):

[image: The code above renders like this]

I did note that your button's left margin appears to be rather large resulting in your button being rendered to the right of the phone's screen. Could this be what's tripping you up?

Alternatively, your FontFamily looks a little unusual. Try omitting your custom font face and seeing if you can get your button to render with standard fonts first.

Comment: no man even if i change the font it doesnt work, and about the margin it displays the text in the phone screen, it just doesnt shows the bordercolor, i even try it in another project and the border isnnt working i dont know what it is